# Run all tests once per each parameter with pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I want to run whole test suite for each parameter in pytest. So lets say i have parameters [a,b,c] and tests test1, test2, test3 - So I want to run all the tests for a and then for b and then for c. Below is the code I have used

```
my_list = [1,2,3]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("a",my_list)
class Test_suite:
     def test_1(self,a):
           #whatever
     def test_2(self,a):
           #whatever
     def test_3(self,a):
           #whatever
```

above code is running as test_1 for [1,2,3] and test_2 for [1,2,3] and so on.
But I need it as test_1,test_2,test_3 for parameter 1 and test_1,test_2,test_3 for parameter 2 and so on. Please help me

Comment: Is the order of execution the only concern here??

Comment: Yes, order of execution I want is run all tests for each parameter

Answer (score 2):

You can use pytest fixtures.

for example:

```
 @pytest.fixture(scope="module", params= my_list)
    def my_params(request):
        retutn request.param
```

Now you can use the fixures in your test cases.

```
class Test_suite:
 def test_1(self,my_params):
       #whatever
 def test_2(self,my_params):
       #whatever
 def test_3(self,my_params):
       #whatever
```

This should solve your issue.